# Using Variables as column names in select statement (problems with single quotes in query)

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I'm making a stored procedure that massages data (about 80 itenerations).   It needs to accept a column name as a variable passed from the 'mother' procedure.

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'update AGP_MPI_PROV_IMPORTFULL_001 SET ' || COLUMN_NAME1 || ' = 
  REPLACE('||COLUMN_NAME1||', ' Ii ',' II ') where '|| column_name1 ||' is not null;'
```

I got that part - but it's massaging data and changing ' Ii' to be ' II ' - it's those devilish single quotes that are kicking my butt.  How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the single-quote by another.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'update AGP_MPI_PROV_IMPORTFULL_001 SET ' || COLUMN_NAME1 || ' = 
   REPLACE('||COLUMN_NAME1||', '' Ii '','' II '') where '|| column_name1 ||' is not null;'
```

Comment: +1. Alternatively, you can use bind variables: `REPLACE('||COLUMN_NAME1||', :to_replace, :replacement)` and `is not null;' USING ' Ii ', ' II ';`.

Comment: @ruakh I haven't oracle background and your version seems more correct for me.